# Random population sample divided into age groups

Tags: r

I want to create a random population data column of around 4000 rows and then randomly distribute each row of this population data column into 4 age group columns (like 0-24, 25-64, 64-85 and 85+).

[image]

Comment: You can check `?cut` or` ?findInterval` by specifying the `breaks`. i.e. `cut(yourvector, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 25, 64, 85, Inf))`

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for the silly reply earlier, I this what you are looking for:

`Population=as.integer(runif(4000,10000,1000000))`

`df <- matrix(runif(16000,0,1), nc=4)`

`df <- sweep(df, 1, rowSums(df), FUN="/")`

`df=as.data.frame(df)`

`df=cbind(Population,df)`

`colnames(df)=c('Population','0-24','25-64','64-85','85 above')`
`df1=cbind(Population,round(df$Population*df[,2:5],0))`

Comment: Thank you, Yogesh. But actually, I want a data frame of a different kind. I have modified my question and added an image to explain it better.